# Keras backend function equivalent for str.format

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensor

How to perform the following function using [Keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/)?

```
"{0:b}".format(37)
```

Comment: Can you provide a use case? What are you trying to achieve that requires you to perform this using the Keras backend? The backend is for *tensor operations* not strings.

Comment: @nuric I was actually trying to apply integer operations on the tensor objects by casting them using K.cast(x, dtype= tf.int32).